# ubuntu one not syncing... in windows XP Sp3

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, windows-7, windows-xp

I already install the Ubuntu One 2.0 to try to connect to my storage, like I had done with beta, all of then installed correctly but when I try to sign in with my account it take a long time to get my information and it doesn't connect.

When I log into the Ubuntu One site I connect without any problem.

---

After one hour I receive a error pop-up with title "ubuntuone-control-panel-qt" with the error message "AttributeError "'NoneType? object has no attribute 'get_rootdir'".

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with Ubuntu 2.0 on Windows 7 (64-bit, German). It took very long to start the program (more than 20 minutes estimated), then the "ubuntuone-control-panel-qt" reported "AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_rootdir'" or "...no attribute 'autoconnect_enabled'".

This was solved when I restarted the computer and then started UbuntuOne with Admin-privileges (right-mouse click on the icon and choose "run as Admin"). The Win-7-firewall displayed a pop-up about letting this program pass the firewall, which I allowed (for home and business-networks only). Now everything works nicely.

In the settings I unchecked the option "Connect automatically when computer starts", because I am unsure whether this automatic start would have the necessary admin rights.